# Multiple group by in (aggregation) Mongo

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, php-mongodb

I trying to group by two different fields in an aggregation in order to avoid duplicating it. I have the below case:

```
'$project' => [
            'type1' => '$field1',
            'type2' => '$field2',
            'category1' => [
                '$cond' => [
                  ['$gt' => ['field3', ' ']],
                  1,
                  0
                  ]
              ],
            'category2' => [
                '$cond' => [
                  ['$eq' => ['$field4', 1]],
                  1,
                  0
                  ]
              ],
           ],

      ],

      ['$group' => [
              '_id'   => '$type1',
              'total' => ['$sum' => 1],
              'category1'  => ['$sum' => '$category1'],
              'category' => ['$sum' => '$category2']
              ]
        ],

      ['$sort' => ['_id.$type1' => 1, '_id.type1' => 1]]
```

In the above example I am grouping them by the $field1. Is it possible in the same aggregation to group the same data by $field 2 too?

Comment: I tend to comment that yes, this should be possible, too. But I'm not so firm w/ that database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible.
If you want to group two fields, then the query is as simple as:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$group:{_id:{field1:"$field1", field2:"$field2"}..other accumulators here..}}    

])
```

Comment: That returns a combination of $field1 and $field2. What I want is to fetch the data separately for each $field. The data should be grouped by $field1 and the same data should be grouped by field2.